# Watertight power connections

Tags: wiring, pool, weather-resistant

Is there something like a water-proof Amphenol-style plug connector for an exterior 12/2 120V power connection?

I have pool pumps hardwired through grey "Sealproof" flex conduit.  I need to remove them seasonally, and I'd rather have a tail on the pump with some sort of watertight power coupler than have to remove the covers of each pump and (un)screw each wire to/from its terminal.

[image: Hardwired exterior pump]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are numerous lines of connectors designed for water-resistant use, or even "waterproof", such as might be used in boating marinas (or on boats) or other places requiring the quick replacement of water-proof appliances.

They typically have an exterior screwshell and interlocking seals.  Here is one example:
[4-pin waterproof cord connector, 5 Amp](http://www.witleds.com/product/IP67-4pin-male-and-female-waterproof-connector.html)

Answer (score 1):

Waterproof (1m) [IP67](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_Code) 230V rated connectors are standardised internationally. The connectors are keyed and colour-coded.

[image]

See [IEC 60309](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60309) - there are numerous manufacturers and suppliers.